# I want to add an image to my button in python but it is showing an error that _tkinter.TclError: image "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/food.webp" doesn't exist

Tags: python, tkinter

## Please see to it as the image is there t the specified path but it always results in an error

```
import tkinter as tk

def r():
    print("Hello")

a=tk.Tk()
f=tk.Frame(a)
f.pack(fill=tk.X)

a.title("Main Win")


i1=tk.PhotoImage.Image=("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/food.webp")


b1= tk.Button(f, text="Print", image=i1, command=r, width="200", height="100")

f.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

a.mainloop()
```

Comment: `tk.PhotoImage.Image=...` is assigning to a meaningless `Image` attribute of the `PhotoImage` class.  It should be something like `tk.PhotoImage(file="...")`, but that's probably not going to work either because `.webp` is not one of the image formats it supports.

Comment: With tk.PhotoImage(file=".....") it is showing: _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\food.webp"

Comment: Tkinter doesn't support files of type .webp.

Comment: Use `Pillow` module which supports `.webp`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that I see that would make this fail Here they are:

1. PhotoImage does not support .webp photos. It only support .pgm .ppm .gif and .png
2. Unless your name us USER, the directory is wrong. You need to put whatever your name you sign in with there.
3. The PhotoImage tk call is done wrong. To display an image, you must have a label, then set the Labels background to the image. And, you call PhotoImage like this: 
   i = tk.PhotoImage(file = "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/food.webp")

Check these, and you will fix your problem.